# Does a PostgreSQL hot standby cache streamed WAL segments?

Tags: postgresql

If pg_xlog_replay_pause() is used or max_standby_streaming_delay is set, are unapplied WAL segments stored on the hot standby?

I'd like to be clear if a long-running query is keeping WAL segments from being applied & the primary server fails if the hot standby will still be able to replay segments to come close to the primary's state just before failure or if the changes on the primary server from the beginning of the long-running query will be lost.

Comment: Take a look at `pg_stat_replication`, in particular `sent_location`, `write_location` and `flush_location`